# Pandas split list inside a column into separate columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset with 71 columns and 113 rows. Each column is a array of values. I want to split these arrays into separate columns. Then rename the columns with the prefix

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/sample/master/audioonly.csv
audio = pd.read_csv("audioonly.csv")
zcr = pd.DataFrame(audio['zcr'].str.split().values.tolist())
zcr.columns = ['zcr_' + str(col)  for col in zcr.columns]
```

I can do it for each column individually and combine as single dataframe.
Please propose a faster method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `concat` and a list comprehension:

```
audio_exploded = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(audio[col].str.split().values.tolist())\
                              .add_prefix(f'{col}_')
                            for col in audio.columns],
                            axis=1)
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
I am getting this

Comment: @pranavnerurkar I though the code you wrote was working for any column?

Comment: hi is there any way i can remove special character likes ',' '[' and ']' from the dataframe cells

Comment: @pranavnerurkar before you can try `audio = audio.replace(',|\[|\]', '', regex=True)` but once again they have to be strings. or even after on `audio_exploded` it should work